# Test RSA Keys For EMV card

Tags: javacard, emv, globalplatform

As per EMV standard we require two RSA keys.

> 1) Issuer RSA Keys ( will use 1408 bit)
>
> 2) ICC RSA Keys    ( will use 1152 bit)

Here Issuer RSA private keys are use to calculate ICC public key certificate. A EMV card contain various Tag like `8F` , `90` (issuer public key certificate) 
`9F46` (ICC PUBLIC KEY CERTIFICATE) etc that use in SDA/DDA.

Actually I want to personalize a EMV card with using java language and want to handle all calculation by my own. this require RSA keys ( SDA/DDA need RSA Stuff)

Also EMV have DGI8201-8205

that contain ICC RSA private key in CRT format.

I know it is very complex but this is only way to understand EMV technology in deep. Could any body tell me how can I get RSA keys that can solve my purpose and can use it in EMV calculation. thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I get RSA keys

You can easily generate your own RSA CRT keys for your testing purpose. I wrote the following code snippet for you to generate RSA CRT 1408 bit. Note, all the interfaces and classes I used will be found in `java.security.*`

```
public static String byteToHex(byte[] data){
    String r = "";
    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        r+=Integer.toString(  (data[i] & 0xff) + 0x100,16).substring(1);
    }   
    return r;
}   

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {      
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyGen.initialize(1408);

    KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

    RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey ) keyPair.getPublic();
    RSAPrivateCrtKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) keyPair.getPrivate();

    System.out.println("Public Modulus: "+  byteToHex(publicKey.getModulus().toByteArray()));
    System.out.println("Public Exponent: "+byteToHex(publicKey.getPublicExponent().toByteArray()));

    System.out.println("Private Modulus: "+byteToHex(privateKey.getModulus().toByteArray()));

    System.out.println("Private Private Exponent: "+byteToHex(privateKey.getPrivateExponent().toByteArray()));
    System.out.println("Private Prime Exponent DP : "+byteToHex(privateKey.getPrimeExponentP().toByteArray())); // d mod (p-1)
    System.out.println("Private Prime Exponent DQ: "+byteToHex(privateKey.getPrimeExponentQ().toByteArray())); // d mod (q-1)

    System.out.println("Private Prime P: "+byteToHex(privateKey.getPrimeP().toByteArray())); // P

    System.out.println("Private Prime Q: "+byteToHex(privateKey.getPrimeQ().toByteArray())); // Q

    System.out.println("Private Coefficient PQ : "+byteToHex(privateKey.getCrtCoefficient().toByteArray()));  // PQ 
}
```

And the generated key components will look like:

```
Public Modulus: 0095c606a1ca4c5e97afa469c29d0bba478ed9d44f736877ab370a003409a1f04598de1638a394d56e296cd8e52ca37883fd43faa6af299c63180068070ee2f5dbb898d65cc76d0f07a5f2ae6c2b703b069ae5edd4b8c07f2cf642f7f687b5da40a0e877bc5e34c6e0a7fcfbd5f0be1504c03eb0e9b6b3893b4f502e495a56d2e5bce8f28bc2d520aac69af021c1646e285ce226a138e8775164f870856b3f327efaeecf77fa67e520fe37aa053e3a7145
Public Exponent: 010001
Private Modulus: 0095c606a1ca4c5e97afa469c29d0bba478ed9d44f736877ab370a003409a1f04598de1638a394d56e296cd8e52ca37883fd43faa6af299c63180068070ee2f5dbb898d65cc76d0f07a5f2ae6c2b703b069ae5edd4b8c07f2cf642f7f687b5da40a0e877bc5e34c6e0a7fcfbd5f0be1504c03eb0e9b6b3893b4f502e495a56d2e5bce8f28bc2d520aac69af021c1646e285ce226a138e8775164f870856b3f327efaeecf77fa67e520fe37aa053e3a7145
Private Private Exponent: 455cab4f9c4f97f329bdbbd90c401529f4a73ee2f8b0a5d31e2f3c7edd0329322224a027e4e215a1e9ff65c764cfe40d446a8a174dc1b8924fd848551478d9a1c330ccfdb4c1f616f5ac9948b1294dbcb659cbb61b45d2df363499320ce43c04c038b3988f062fcc1d6d3dfcc7a6ff6ad160ace5c8f14662c9f8cc69f790463d65e20cfffea2a3ecd0626b207acad31b25d46688d3facd157285847e08511e8127dc4bdea9ffc1c3b57f1e8be04f9275
Private Prime Exponent DP : 00d634ed8f011db920750a594d23b6066a2181ae8378d5f90b4e701b634f9378c1215015c875b7e852118ed92433772b01f6d315813d45de63edd9f8acee4d819f320e7b50c819160621450a673ea7b61678d1b50a2a13059f
Private Prime Exponent DQ: 1e6bf49a032f5168cfb5817f51f6dac5613bd769c56b96008ca3b1f2e62824efcefd1cfc827c08efd42190db0de54d12b2296b67f71dfc24e9d58927ad61ff3b5492225a84d35188a38f32a9aea0287fe597af3d76540e49
Private Prime P: 00f88b11b520fc307cdddc8f0526172b7d0d25bffb3f46005bfc686101ebea8df24b657abe2118c74968e3106f39ef1b080d9eb134efcaf85a603ae9e8b0a9d5dc8bee0ee3d1de88a57b432080afd99657cdf6bc3a35962fcb
Private Prime Q: 009a445bb5fe1ff143eca24abb8852a76c3b4a40ec5dead5602948f1f2b0e8365a3e885bc886dd48e4219f46d898c465936fb8536144a7674c1a31f9c3c11f63623e8b1c60ce4746d53c737c55479555f7e16871e135aba12f
Private Coefficient PQ : 00b21001cee21e109dfd63dc39c7315bbf45faa835c22c9d0cd1d109c9843fc00285adc7f6bc0cf66e855c2e7155d104858845b9ab5c5ce8db95c65dd566e41ef938d5c594de5af8fda13a32e82162d4b730a453625c2d7783
```

**EDIT:** You can create your own key generation spec, for example:

```
RSAKeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = 
              new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(1408, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F0);

KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(keyGenParameterSpec);
//.... rest of the code will be the same I posted above
```

And this time you will get:

```
Public Exponent: 03
```

Comment: Hello Rakeb, It is really great. I tested it and found OK. Could you tell me how we can decide that we have keys with Exponent = 03 not 65537?? this code is returning 65537 for both 1152 and 1408 bit key.

Comment: Really it is a great support from you.  Here we can start some calculation with these keys.